# Sort the date in the format as "2020-12-30T02:07:08.500254-05:00"

Tags: json, string, date

In one of the json response, I am receiving the date like this in string format "2020-12-30T02:07:08.500254-05:00". Now my requirement is like I need to sort the json based on the date. It is not able to convert the above string in to date format to use the sort function.

Need help to sort this date format.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "start":"2019-12-30T02:07:08.500254-05:00",
      "subject":"test1",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "start":"2020-12-30T02:07:08.500254-05:00",
      "subject":"test2",
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "start":"2018-12-30T02:07:08.500254-05:00",
      "subject":"test3",
   }
]
```

Code I am trying to sort the data is

```
db.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a.start).getTime() - new Date(b.start).getTime();});
```

Comment: What language?  JSON itself has no sorting functionality, etc.  If it's Java, you should be using the new [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).  As an aside, if all the timestamps have the same offset, you don't need to convert them, as they'll sort correctly based on the string format data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix it myself. Here is the code

```
function db_sort(a, b){
var a = Date.parse(a.start.substring(0,23) + a.start.substring(26));
var b = Date.parse(b.start.substring(0,23) + b.start.substring(26));
return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime();
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring data sub-millisecond, which means things could be out of order.